# How to install Deluge on Centos?

Tags: linux, python, centos, deluge

I have a problem with installing & running Deluge torrent on my Centos 5 (x86) . I get it from http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/deluge/ this:
_http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/deluge/deluge-0.5.8.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm

after installing, when I run deluge I get this problem:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/deluge", line 43, in ?
    import deluge
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/deluge/__init__.py", line 36, in ?
    import gtk.glade
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 76, in ?
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

No way root I am or user. Same thing. Python version is 2.4.3 . This is server & no X-windows installed on it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I just want to install deluge-core, deluge-webui, deluge-console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest updating both Python and Deluge. Deluge is now on version 1.2.0, miles ahead of 0.5.8.6. I have Deluge (latest) running with [Python 2.6.4](http://python.org/download/) smoothly.

Not only does it appear your version is looking for Python 2.4, but it also wants to open a display. Ensure you are using proper command-line arguments for console mode as David outlined. You must first start the daemon before connecting via console. See the Deluge FAQ on [the console and daemon](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#HowdoIconnecttheconsoleUItoadaemononanon-defaultport).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Python. It's looking for version 2.4.

Incidentally, if you have no X-windows then you'll be better off trying rtorrent - a CLI bittorrent client.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake. Python's version is 2.4.3. Thank's, but I need only deluge or ktorrent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you tried to start Deluge like this:

```
deluge
```

For a command line based interface you can do this:

```
deluge --ui null
```

or:

```
deluge --ui console
```

Or for a web-based interface:

```
deluge --ui web
```

For more info, see Deluge's [FAQ](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#Howtostartthevarioususer-interfaces) on the topic

Comment: Same thing. Even deluge --version displays that error message. Thanks for reply.

Comment: The readme seems to provide some different options.

http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/browser/trunk/README

It may be that deluge was linked to deluge-gtk by the RPM. You can try the following options: deluge-console, deluge-web. Or to just start the daemon, deluged. You can look at the README for further info.